# hyperlink to google search in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I am using jsp to fetch a movie name from mysql db and display it on browser. I want to make the name as a hyperlink, which on being clicked leads to google search of that movie.

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    </head>
    <style>
    body {

    background-size:     cover;                      
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position:  ;              
    }

   </style>
   <body background="N.jpg">
   <FONT color="#19334d" size="5">

    <p>
   </br>
   <center>
   <b>
   <h2>Top 10 recommendations for you</h3>
   <%

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movies","root","");    
    String encArray = request.getParameter("fib");
    String decArray = URLDecoder.decode(encArray,"utf-8");
    String [] str = decArray.split(",");
    int num[] = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        num[i]=Integer.parseInt(str[i].trim());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement("Select title from mydatabase where movieid =?");
         ps.setInt(1,num[i]);
         ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
         while(rs.next()){
             String name  = rs.getString("title");

             out.print(i+1 + "->");
             out.println(name);

             out.println("<br>");
             out.println("<br>");
         }

     }
     %>
```

What I want is that on clicking a movie name , it should lead to its google(pref imdb) search page.    see image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BasG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String name  = rs.getString("title");
out.println("<a href=\"https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+name+"\">"+name+"</a>");
```

Comment: are you sure about a single quote before <a(i.e '<a), it is showing invalid character constant

Comment: Sorry, i'm a PHP guy, just trying to help. Let me update.